# Photo Gallery Not Aligning Adjacently

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to create a responsive photo gallery following this tutorial.
I have a component called `MemoryList` which is defined as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

import {MemoryItem} from "./MemoryItem";

class MemoryList extends React.Component {

  renderItems() {
    return _.map(this.props.memory, (memory, index) => <MemoryItem key={index} {...memory}
                                                                   deleteFunc={this.props.deleteFunc}/>)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="image-row">
          <div className={'column'}>
            {this.renderItems()}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  }

}
export {MemoryList}
```

And also I have my css:

```
.image-row {
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 50%;
        flex: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 100%;
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

So I am trying to make 4 columns of images. Each column is represented by my `MemoryList`. The `MemoryList` takes an array of objects which is then used to create a `MemoryItem`:

```
class MemoryItem extends React.Component {

  renderAction(){
    const profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    const memory_user = this.props.user;

    if (profile.username === memory_user){
      return (
          <button name={this.props.id} className={'btn btn-primary'} onClick={this.props.deleteFunc}>Delete</button>
      )
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
          <img name={this.props.id} className={"img-thumbnail"} src={this.props.image_url} alt={'N/A'}/>
    )
  }
}
```

However, the `MemoryLists` are not being placed adjacently rather underneath each other. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the only problem I can see is you have added padding and flex: 25% to the column. So you have to subtract it from the width otherwise it will push the fourth column to next or you can use justify content to give even spacing like this :-

```
.image-row {
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
    -ms-flex: 23%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 23%;
    max-width: 23%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}
```

Thats for the normarl screen and same thing for media queries as well as substract the padding from the width :-

```
/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 48%;
        flex: 48%;
        max-width: 48%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not working at all or for a specific screen it’s not working. If you can make a code sample on sandbox then I can look into it.